# Solr Facet Filter - q vs fq returning different results?

Tags: solr

Can anybody tell me why these Solr queries would return vastly different results:

```
q=BBC+Food&fq=Source:"BBC-WORLDWIDE"
```

and

```
q=(BBC+Food)+AND+(Source:"BBC-WORLDWIDE")
```

The first returns 6 results, and the latter 58.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the first query is searching for documents that contain both the words BBC AND Food. The second query is searching for either of the words using OR logic.

By placing the keywords in parenthesis, and combining it with any other clause, Solr appears to be inverting the implied "AND" logic for the keywords and instead applying "OR" logic.

The following queries demonstrate this a little better:

> q=(BBC+Food)
>
> q=(BBC+Food)+AND+(BBC+Food)

They both return very much different results because the keywords have reversed logic applied.

Answer (score 2):

Can you add `&debugQuery=on` to the end of your queries and see if the values in the debug output lend any insight into the different between the two queries?